# How to extract words in paragraph with notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How to extract words in every paragraph using notepad++, for example I have sort paragraph that contains word:

> Get no more time. Time was change. Time will never be back again. Time was change. Time. No more time

The result I want is a list of every word (the extract of paragraph) with "No Ignore Case Sensitive" like this:

> Get, no, more, time, Time, was, change, will, never, be, back, again, No

Comment: Some words seem to randomly be missing from your expected CSV output.  Can you explain this?

Comment: What do you mean with "expected CSV output"?

Comment: Are you looking for every word, minus punctuation, or every unique word, or something else?

Comment: I guess what you mean is every word without repetition. You will need some programming to sort out result from regex.

Comment: That is not a job for Npp, you'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Yes, Rahul. I need every words without  repetition.

Answer (score 1):

- Press Ctrl + H
- Find What: Input String
- Replace with: ,
- Search Mode: Regular Expression
- Click: Replace All

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open find and replace dialog box.
2. Find with `(?i)([A-Za-z]+)(?!.*?\1)` and replace with `##\1`

**Note:-** `(?i)` is for ignoring case. `Time` and `time` will b treated as one match.

3. Find with `\s(?!#)\S*` and replace with `` i.e nothing.
4. Find with `\.|##` and replace with `` i.e nothing.
5. Find with `\s+` and replace with `,` i.e a comma.

Comment: Hi rahul, I use s

Comment: From this sentence (short paragraph)<br/>  _Get no more time. Time was change. Time will never be back again. Time was change. Time. No more time_ <br/><br/>Hi rahul, I use step number 5, almost true, but there is still double words or more. In this case, if I double click word " time", it still shows 6 times. <br/> I mean, it will shows only: time, Time. <br/>and if you add 'times' it will shows 3 words: time, Time, times. <br/> <br/>somebody can help?

Comment: @walidin: I understand. What you mean is the case should be taken into consideration. Modified my answer. Added `(?i)` for case insensitive in **step 2**. Try and see.

Comment: Hi @rahul, can you screenshot your trial for me?

Comment: I still fail to do that

Comment: or can you give a demo?